# Retrive data from Broken + Locked Screen Samsung Galaxy S Duos

Tags: backup

Today, I used a third party ordinary charger with my Samsung Galaxy S Duos (s7562), and was shocked to see that the screen touch stopped working.

Earlier, whenever I used to use third party charger, the screen used to behave insanely. But, once I unplugged the charger everything was normal. So, I tried to stick to the original Samsung Charger. Today, my cousin went out with original charger and I used the third party for approximately 10 minute. The touch is not responding anymore, but phone is functional. Home button, power button and volume keys are working but not touch. Display is all fine. I tried : 
1. Restarting phone after keeping out battery for 5 minutes.
2. Enter recovery mode, clear cache partition.
3. Enter recovery mode, reboot.
4. Physically knocking the edges of touch screen smoothly to fix any loosen connection.

But nothing worked. So, the last thing to test is to FACTORY RESET the phone. Now the problem is I use PIN Lock to lock the screen for security Reasons. And I have very very important photos, Messages and Contacts in  my phone.I have controlled my phone earlier with PC Via Bluetooth. And I dont think this cheap crap supports OTG Mouse. Is there any Method to get back my Data by unlocking the phone via PC ?

I know All minds on Stack exchange are intelligent and somebody must show me the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the phone, but with the charger!

I've experienced this as well with cheap crapware (possibly Chinese-made). The reason they cause this behavior is the cheap design that doesn't provide a sufficient decoupling of the voltage and also a bad ripple current.

Furthermore, they do not meet any safety standards. The one I used blew the fuse of my house. Thankfully, no other devices damaged. Also, a Chinese woman has reportedly been electrocuted by using a cheap charger.  Whether it's true or not, I strongly advise against using those chargers. It doesn't have to be from the phone manufacturer, but it's for sure a good idea to get some quality (and none-fake!) charger.

Once you use the original charger again, your phone should be working again normally.

PS:
Read this article for an in-depth explanation at the example of fake iPhone-chargers
http://www.righto.com/2012/03/inside-cheap-phone-charger-and-why-you.html

Comment: I support your view. I am not going to buy any chinese craps in future. But I am very sorry to say that Its not the answer to my question. Is there any option to get even 10% data out of my phone ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the final answer. I just edited. Did you try with the original charger again?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Hard Reset My Phone *out of frustation*. **Problem Not Solved** :( Touch Still not responding. If anybody Facing the same problem, dont Format your valuable data. Better to go for Hardware repair.

Didn't get any answer of My question. And, never use cheap chinese chargers.

Comment: Did you try using the original charger again, that your cousin took from you?